# How to change background on python file cell VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how I can change the background, or even the border color, of a cell in a python file in VS Code? I'm not looking to change the colors in the interactive window, I'd like to do it for a particular cell (picture attached) either for the background of the cell (bracket) or the borders (pointing arrows): [Screenshot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb1AT.png). For example, I would like the blue lines that the arrows are pointing to, to be white instead. How can I change that?

I am just learning to use VS Code (and Python) and have gone to [Theme Color | VSC Extension API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#notebook-colors), but I can't seem to pinpoint it..

Comment: You should give jupyter notebooks a go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in the settings.json file:

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "peekView.border": "#ffffff"
  },
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!